# Magento not showing CMS Page content

Tags: cms

My local installation shows content on every existing cms page.

The remote installation show no content on  none of the cms blocks.

File basis is the same for both. Cache is off. Content is existing.
The only page showing content is the cms page. 
If I analysis the blocks, everything is there and correctly nested.

Any hints what could cause the issue?

Comment: Sounds like the incorrect store is set or something like that. Make sure the content is assigned to the right store